# .htaccess Redirect Without The Question Mark

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am looking to redirect the URL `http://www.example.com/user_pages/home_0.shtml?page=Home` to `http://www.example.com/`.  I have it redirecting to `http://www.example.com/?` using the following RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user_pages/home_0.shtml http://www.example.com/?
```

I was hoping that someone could help me figure out how to remove the trailing question mark.  I understand that is the way I have it setup but that is the farthest I could get to matching what I need.

Secondary question but I think it falls in line with what I am doing here.  I have the following RedirectMatch setup:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user_pages/contactus_0.shtml http://www.example.com/help.php?section=contactus&mode=update
```

I am attempting to redirect `http://www.example.com/user_pages/contactus_0.shtml?page=Contact%20Us` to `http://www.example.com/help.php?section=contactus&mode=update` but I end up with `http://www.example.com/help.php?section=contactus/user_pages/contactus_0.shtmlmode=update`.  I understand this is caused by the additional query string but I am at a lose on how to fix.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Last part is not quite clear. ¿Do you want `http://www.example.com/user_pages/contactus_0.shtml?page=Contact%20Us` to be redirected to `http://www.example.com/help.php?section=contactus&mode=update` or is it the order way around? If, in fact, the question reflects what you want, ¿how do you expect anyone to enter **page=Contact%20Us**?

Comment: You are correct in your first statement.  We are taking over an old site and that is the cached version of the contact page in Google.  So we want to put a 301 redirect on it to the new contact page.  I have gotten almost working using the example you gave me below.  I am using the following:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=Contact%20Us.*$   
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/help.php?section=contactus&mode=update? [L,R=301]`

Comment: which results in the following URL `http://www.example.com/help.php?section=contactus&mode=update%3f`. So it looks like `%3f` is the trailing ? I was adding to the statement.  I have removed that resulting in `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=Contact%20Us.*$   
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/help.php?section=contactus&mode=update [L,R=301]` which works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to remove the **?** of the query is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Test for a query with `page=`
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=.*$   
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com? [L,R=301]
```

The last **?** will remove the query including **?**

As for the last part of the question, please check my comment.